Order of step properties in AzureDevops pipeline
In an ADO pipeline, I have a step using PowerShell task in shortcut form like this:
- powershell: |
    some script here
  name: MyStep
  displayName: 'My Step'

I get an error when I change the order of properties in this yaml object to this:
- name: MyStep
  displayName: 'My Step'
  powershell: |
    some script here

The error:

(Line: 120, Col: 17): Unexpected value 'name'

Aren't these objects the same except different properties order? Am I missing something or is it ADO being weird again! :D

You can change the order of the properties EXCEPT the first one, which indicates the type of the task.

Check this doc: steps.powershell definition.
when you define:
steps:
- powershell

it will be parsed as steps.powershell
in the second case:
steps:
- name: MyStep

it will be parsed as steps.name and you`ll see the error.

Seem to be a reasonable explanation.
